# How to Convert a Time to local Time in Different TimeZone

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, timezone, timezone-offset

Currently i am working on a chat project from where many users can communicate through each other sitting across the globe. ie: Different TimeZone.  eg.
1st in India
2nd in America
3rd in Russia
4th in Australia

I am saving my message sent time into database as DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime()
Issue i am getting is if any user **sent message** he gets correct time like 1 min ago but rest will get time like 4 hours ago . Every person sitting across different countries should get 1 Min ago
I am using javascript to get timezone like

```
 var offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
 $("#timezoneOffset").val(offset); //setting timezone in hidden field and save as cookie.
```

To Convert UTC time from database to show client time difference :

```
var timeOffSet = Request.Cookies["timeoffset"].Value;
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime("2015-06-15 12:13:12");
if (timeOffSet != null)
{
    var offset = int.Parse(timeOffSet.ToString());
    dt = dt.AddMinutes(-1 * offset);
    model.SentDate = FormatTime.TimeAgo(dt);
}
```

This message I sent from india with above time, I Get a seconds ago but my partner sitting in North America gets 4 hours ago.

What i am Doing Wrong?  My Code to convert DateTime in ago format is:

```
public static string TimeAgo(DateTime dt)
{
    TimeSpan span = DateTime.Now - dt;
    if (span.Days > 365)
    {
        int years = (span.Days / 365);
        if (span.Days % 365 != 0)
            years += 1;
        return String.Format("about {0} {1} ago",
        years, years == 1 ? "year" : "years");
    }
    if (span.Days > 30)
    {
        int months = (span.Days / 30);
        if (span.Days % 31 != 0)
            months += 1;
        return String.Format("about {0} {1} ago",
        months, months == 1 ? "month" : "months");
    }
    if (span.Days > 0)
        return String.Format("about {0} {1} ago",
        span.Days, span.Days == 1 ? "day" : "days");
    if (span.Hours > 0)
        return String.Format("about {0} {1} ago",
        span.Hours, span.Hours == 1 ? "hour" : "hours");
    if (span.Minutes > 0)
        return String.Format("about {0} {1} ago",
        span.Minutes, span.Minutes == 1 ? "minute" : "minutes");
    if (span.Seconds > 5)
        return String.Format("about {0} seconds ago", span.Seconds);
    if (span.Seconds <= 5)
        return "just now";
    return string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: Use NodaTime by Jon Skeet (y)

Comment: where to use NodaTime ?? I'll try but it will save my time if you please set me a example @Randolph

Comment: https://github.com/nodatime/nodatime :) this it the project on GitHub. Here is the site: http://nodatime.org. You can find plenty of examples there ;)

Comment: Why would you send the *local* time from the client at all? (I'd also recommend using `DateTime.UtcNow` instead of getting the local time at the server and converting it...) Also note that the time zone offset *right now* may not be the same as the offset at other points in time.

Comment: Yes, persist everything as UTC. Then convert back and forth for the interface as needed.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezone.currenttimezone%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 The only bad part is the timezone takes the value of the nearest internet hub not the actual local computer.  This can be corrected by using the local JavaScript hour with Datetime.UtcNow

Comment: @artisdextrus - what you are saying about "nearest internet hub" is not correct.  That method makes no network calls at all.  Also, the local time zone of the server is irrelevant to this problem, and the `TimeZone` class should be treated as deprecated.

Comment: @Randolph - Thanks for the promo, but please refrain from link-only responses.  If you have an answer to add that *uses* Noda Time in the context of this question, then please do.  But there are thousands of datetime/timezone related questions, and "use Noda Time" is not an answer for them all. :)

Comment: Thanks everyone. Just from your feedback I have corrected the issues and problem fixed :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem I see with your code is the first line in your `TimeAgo()` method: The `DateTime dt` object you pass to this method is local time for your clients, but then you use the server local time `DateTime.Now` to calculate the timespan.

Pass the UTC timestamps you get from your DB to this method directly and replace `DateTime.Now` with `DateTime.UtcNow`.

Comment: +1 for the first two paragraphs, but the last one is not necessary.  Once the time recorded is in UTC, and the comparison is made against UTC, then the client's time zone becomes irrelevant.

Comment: However, just for your own knowledge, the offset would indeed have to be negated to convert from UTC to local time, because JS gets the offset with positive values *east* of UTC, which is the opposite of the normal convention.

Comment: @MattJohnson Thanks, you are right, I removed that part of my answer.